# How to split a string in java using stringtokenizer by dynamic data

Tags: java

I'm getting dynamic data from Database,that is in format of **/name/exam/0oecda251d73jf82m33m92/run**.

But now I want only **0oecda251d73jf82m33m92** how to get this in Java. I tried with **stringtokenizer** class but not get correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a *regular expression* and a `Pattern`. Something like,

```
String str = "/name/exam/0oecda251d73jf82m33m92/run";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/.*/.*/(.*)/run");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**or** use `String.split(String)`; the [`StringTokenizer` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says (in part) *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.*

Something like,

```
String[] arr = str.split("/");
if (arr.length > 3) {
    System.out.println(arr[3]);
}
```

Both of which output

```
0oecda251d73jf82m33m92
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function of String class.

```
String s[] = "/name/exam/0oecda251d73jf82m33m92/run".split("/");
System.out.println(s[3]);
```

As the above answer said it is not recommended to use `StringTokenizer` in new code if you want to work with `split`.

Comment: **split** is working fine.Thank you for your response.